# Difference between 'Team-> Update to HEAD' and 'Replace With-> Latest from Repository'?

Tags: svn, subclipse

What is the difference between the `Team-> Update to HEAD` and `Replace With-> Latest from Repository`? I frequently use both of them but never know the difference.

Note: My platform is Ubuntu, Eclipse Kepler with Subclipse 1.8.x

Comment: Neither of those are terminology from TortoiseSVN or the standard svn command-line. What client are you *really* using?

Comment: It's Subclipse 1.8.x plugin in eclipse. I've updated the note in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be explained in the Subclipse help that comes with the plugin.

`Team -> Update to HEAD` is the equivalent of `svn update` - the current state of the latest revision is merged into your WC with any local uncommitted changes you might have. Work should not be lost (you may have a merge conflict)

`Replace with -> Latest from Repository` ignores local changes and replaces your local copy with the latest version in the repository. Local uncommitted changes will be lost.

Comment: what is project -> team->upgrade for? and one more thing i'm using subclipse, svn ,maven in eclipse for JEE application so how should i update my project first maven update next svn update to head or svn update to head next maven update?

Comment: @MahenderReddyYasa if you have your own questions about using Subclipse, Eclipse and/or Maven, please post them as new questions, not comments on old answers.